# What is limiting network bandwidth between my EC2 nodes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I copy files from an `i3.metal` instance to a `t3.medium` instance with 16Gb `sc1` EBS disk. Both located in `us-west-2` (Oregon) region (though in different AZs). The speed was up to 200Mb/s for some time but then dropped to only 30Mb/s!

[image]

See the CloudWatch graph. There are "bytes per minute" on the Y-axis, so 12G peak corresponds to 200Mb/s, and then 2G plateau corresponds to ~30Mb/s.

`i3.metal` is said to have 25Gbit/s (3125Mb/s) network, `t3.medium` is said to have up to 5Gbit/s (625 Mb/s) network. 16Gb `sc1` disk baseline IO throughput [should be 192Mb/s](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-volume-types.html#EBSVolumeTypes_sc1). IIUC, there are no limitations on the SSDs on the `i3.metal`, besides the physical speed. But clearly, something is limiting my speed. Could anyone suggest what this can be?

Comment: I wouldn't think CPU would be an issue here, but the graph does look a bit like you exhausted CPU credits on the t3. Is it set to unlimited?

Comment: OMG, seems like you are correct. I did not expect network consumes so much CPU. Thanks a lot!

Comment: "Network" does not consume CPU, but whatever you were running that was utilising the network also consumed CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jordanm pointed out in the comments, the problem is in the CPU, which is quite slow on the `t3.medium` machine. One can clearly see how the graphs are correlated, and how I exhaust my CPU credits.
[image]